# ListFields (arcpy) not reading from layer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have a very simple python script that opens an mxd from a folder and then loops through each layer, and finds a ObjectID field and changes the alias name.

```
#setup
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

#Go into folder where mxd's are
env.workspace = r"D:\Temp\Test_Mxd"
#for each mxd
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print "Working on map document: " + mxd
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("D:\\Temp\\Test_Mxd\\" + mxd)
    #   for each dataframe
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc,"Layers")[0]
    ##layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc,"*",df):
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc,"*",df)

    #   for each layer
    for layer in layers:
        print "Working on layer: " + layer.name
        **fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(layer)**
        for field in fieldList:
            if field.name == "OBJECTID":
        # Set the new alias name
                field.aliasName == "IGNORE::OBJECTID"
    mapdoc.save()
del mxd
```

my problem is on the line `fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(layer)`, I get a error in the interpreter (pythonwin) which says that the layer does not exist.
Has anyone got any idea on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001p000000) says that ListFields takes a String parameter. So I would try with the datasource path, rather than a layer object itself.
I.e. something like:

```
if layer.supports("DATASOURCE"):
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(layer.dataSource)
```

Comment: This only list fields from feature class but not all fields (related tables). In ArcMap, arcpy.ListFields method lists all the fields.